# Batch/vbs to read a text file

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, wsh

I want to write a batch script / vbs that should read a text file line by line and search for a keyword. if the keyword is found, it should redirect to the output file.

The sample log is as follow,

Tue 01/09/2000
06:53 PM
--------C:\Data--------
C:\Data\2009
C:\Data\2010
C:\Data\2011
C:\Data\Filename.txt
C:\Data\Fileusage
C:\Data\Guidline.xml
C:\Data\2009\12
C:\Data\2009\12\01\667e33999.txt
C:\Data\2009\12\01\667e45454999.xml
C:\Data\2009\12\09\667dfder999.pdf
C:\Data\2009\12\09\667e332324.pdf
C:\Data\2009\12\09\867fdfe2323.pdf
C:\Resource\Findings\233.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\234.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\235.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\236.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\237.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\238.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\433.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\239.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\890.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\121.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\009.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\999.txt
Total Files Listed:
12 File(s) 7,234,336 bytes
0 Dir(s) 3,413,392,345 bytes free

Basically i want to capture any line that starts with C:\Data\Year\Month and C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted

The output as below

C:\Data\2009\12\01\667e33999.txt
C:\Data\2009\12\01\667e45454999.xml
C:\Data\2009\12\09\667dfder999.pdf
C:\Data\2009\12\09\667e332324.pdf
C:\Data\2009\12\09\867fdfe2323.pdf
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\433.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\239.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\890.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\121.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\009.txt
C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\999.txt

Anyone can give me a hand ?

Comment: What is your current code? Read `for /?`, `cmd /?` and `set /?` or look at [dostips.com](http://www.dostips.com)

Comment: @jeb: It's way easier than that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findstr`:

```
findstr /b /r "C:\\Resource\\Findings\\Lasted\\ C:\\Data\\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9]\\." data.dump
```

`findstr` is for filtering lines from a file which is what we're doing here. First we enable regular expression matching with `/r`. Don't be deceived, those are very, very minimal regexes that break every now and then so it can be tricky to get them right. `/b` is for matching the beginning of a line. Then there is a space-separated list of things to look for, in this case either `C:\Resource\Findings\Lasted\` or `C:\Data\Year\Month` where the year has four and the month two digits.

Comment: I think also about findstr, but I supposed that it can't search for two different strings in the regEx-Basic mode

Comment: below is my batch script.. Anyone can help me fix it ?         @echo off > result & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir/b file.txt') do (
findstr /b /r "C:\\Resource\\Findings\\Lasted\\ C:\\Data\\[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\\[0-9][0-9]\\."  < %%i >> result.txt
)

Comment: @user: Ask a question the normal way (and include way more information, please). Random comments on random answers that just happen to be roughly related are usually ignored (which I will do as well right now).